# What design could fit this egg drop challenge?

Tags: design, building-design, building-physics

My class is doing the egg drop challenge as a school project, but the rules are a little different than normal. First of all, the construction needs to contain a microbit connected to a battery pack that will measure speed, acceleration, and so on... This will be used to plot graphs of the movement of the egg later on. The battery pack and microbit weigh about the same as the egg

The egg will be dropped from a height of 8 meters and you have to aim for a blink.

We are also given points based on the performance of the drop (more points are worse):

- 0.1 points for each 10 cm the egg misses its mark
- 0.1 points for each travel second
- 0.1 points for every 20 grams the constructions weigh
- 10 points if the egg cracks

A parachute design would not be the best because of the time. I was thinking about maybe doing a cage-type of design like this:
[image: Cage design]

But its probably possible to do a lighter design. Does anyone have some design ideas which could perform well in this scenario?

Comment: So you want to submit our work as your contribution?

Comment: I was simply asking for design ideas.

Comment: replace the straws supporting the egg with springs.

Comment: Is there a definition of what causes the "egg to crack"? How much prototyping and testing are you able to do? Fall time will be 1-2 seconds unless you go for a parachute, which would hurt your accuracy. 100 plastic straws would weigh  about 40g- so it makes sense to focus on optimising for accuracy.

Comment: If something pops out of the egg, it's cracked. I can do as much testing as I want without the egg, but I have three eggs that I can use in total. So basically two tests with an egg if I save the last one for the competition itself.

Comment: Another problem is that the accuracy of the drop is measured from the point the construction stops. Meaning it could be an accurate drop, but then roll/move away from the blink.